# How do I add the same entry to multiple databases with same table?

Tags: sql

All databases have the same table (dbo.mtUsers). Also all databases have almost the same name (MTMaster14_1; MTMaster14_2, MTMaster14_* and so on ~300 dbs)

Is it possible to add the same entry to multiple databases with same table?

Comment: have you checked out sp_MSforeachdb?

Comment: @neuhaus remember, be nice, it's clear what the question is

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database vendor (and the term "database" means something different for each vendor). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' LIKE ''MTMaster14_%'' BEGIN USE ? INSERT dbo.mtUsers () VALUES () END' 

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Source Link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested this query but am getting this error:

Query:
SELECT @command = ' IF ''?'' LIKE ''MTMaster14_%'' BEGIN USE ? INSERT dbo.mtUsers (id) VALUES (DOMAIN\USER)'

Error:
Incorrect syntax near '\'

Tried to use ('DOMAIN\USER') also ("DOMAIN\USER") also (' 'DOMAIN\USER' ') but none of these worked.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was missing the `END` at the end of the `@command`.  You should be able to use `(''DOMAIN\USER'')`

Comment: @MartynasŠavelis if I answered your question, please accept this post as the answer.